# Favorite List with Firestore in Android Studio with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

i try to implement a favorite List in Android Studio with Kotlin.
In Firestore i have a favorite collection. The documents are stored with the userId and the field keys are the documentIds from the favorite objects. Value is true.

I have problems to display the Favorite List in the RecyclerView, because of the asynch read of firebase. Is there any option to wait until the SnapshotListener finished his task?

```
val documentRefFavorite = db.collection("Favorites").document(userId)


    var listFavorites = ArrayList<String>()
    listFavorites.add("")

    documentRefFavorite.addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, firebaseFirestoreException ->
        val favoriteMap: MutableMap<String, Any> = documentSnapshot?.data as MutableMap<String, Any>
        favoriteMap.forEach {
            listFavorites.add(it.key.toString().trim())
        }
    }

    val queryFavorites = db.collection("Spots")
        .whereIn("id", listFavorites)
        //.orderBy("name", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
```

Comment: How about setting the recyclerview adapter after favoriteMap.forEach { } but inside addSnapshotListener . Data in recyclerview will be shown as the data is recieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to wait for asynchronous code to finish in Android. The solution is to put any code that needs the data from the database into the callback that's invoked when the data is loaded.

So in your case that'd be something like:

```
val documentRefFavorite = db.collection("Favorites").document(userId)

var listFavorites = ArrayList<String>()
listFavorites.add("")

documentRefFavorite.addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, firebaseFirestoreException ->
    val favoriteMap: MutableMap<String, Any> = documentSnapshot?.data as MutableMap<String, Any>
    favoriteMap.forEach {
        listFavorites.add(it.key.toString().trim())
    }
    val queryFavorites = db.collection("Spots")
        .whereIn("id", listFavorites)
        //.orderBy("name", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
}
```

Comment: The problem is, i have to start the FirestoreRecyclerListener in the onStart() and onStop() methode. When i implement the Query and the FirestoreRecyclerOptions in the addSnapshotListener the FirestoreRecyclerListener is not init.

Comment: You should call `startListening` when you have all the information that is needed to start listening. For simple reads that is typically in `onStart`, but it's just as common to do that in a lower level in your code.

Comment: Is there any downside when i call the startListening in the addSnapshotListener? I'm really new to Android programming and it's for an University Project. So there is no Productive Usecase behind this application.

Comment: Downside: not really. That call is just what starts reading from/observing the database, so you can call it wherever works for your app. Inside `onStart` is just that place for most initial use-cases, but you seem to have a need to do it later, and that's fine too.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help. Struggle the last few hours without finding a good solution.